# Mongoose - populate match String in array doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to search objects with Mongoose (v4.6.2) using populate. Here are my models (in two different files) :

```
const experienceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, maxlength: 50 },
  creator: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  creatorName: String,
  city: { type: String, maxlength: 64 },
  interests: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Interest' }],
}, { timestamps: true });

const interestSchema = new Schema({
  Name: { type: String, default: '' },
  illustration: { type: String, default: '' },
}, { timestamps: true });
```

Then I have an array : ["pizza", "GOT"]. So I want to fin all experiences which have at least one interest of the array. So i do this :

```
experienceModel.find()
.populate({
     path: 'interests',
     match: { Name: { $in: array }}
})
.exec(function(err, exps) {...}
```

Then, I don't know why, the result contains experiences which have no interests, especially those of the array :(

Do you see where the problem could comes from ?

Thank you, have a nice day :)

Comment: Your query will find _all_ experiences. The `match` property for `populate()` is only used in the population step, which happens _after_ the initial query has been performed.

Comment: Oh ok.. So do you know how I could request the experience which have at least one word of the array in their experiences ?

Comment: You first need to find the `_id` properties of the interests that you want to search for, and use these to query the experiences: `experienceModel.find({ interests : { $in : arrayOfInterestIds } })`